# Seeded region growing with opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I need to select a pixel value and apply the region growing in terms of the seed pixel. After trying to write the code, the result was always a black image
regardless of what seed point I used. The whole problem is involved in the `GrowColor` function. My guess is a logical error with the ifs.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace std;

int xDim, yDim, zDim;
float ThreshHold = 45.0;
unsigned long total[3];
int coont, tt;
IplImage *Image1;
IplImage *Image2;

CvScalar s = cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0);
CvScalar s11 = cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0);

int Diff, mean[3], temp[3];

void GrowColor(int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char value[4];

    int pixType, dimCut;
    int Dbug = false;
    int Xseed = 40, Yseed = 234;
    int i = 0, x, y;
    Image1 = cvLoadImage("lenah.jpg");
    yDim = Image1->height;
    xDim = Image1->width;
    // int step= Image1->widthStep;
    //uchar* data = (uchar *)Image1->imageData;

//New image
    Image2 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(Image1->width, Image1->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U,
            1);
    cvZero(Image2);
    total[0] = total[1] = total[2] = coont = 0;

//Process

    for (y = Yseed - 5; y <= Yseed + 5; y++)
        for (x = Xseed - 5; x <= Xseed + 5; x++)
            if ((x > 0) && (y > 0) && (x < xDim) && (y < yDim)) {

                coont++;
                s = cvGet2D(Image1, x, y);
                total[0] += abs(s.val[0]);
                total[1] += abs(s.val[1]);
                total[2] += abs(s.val[2]);

            }

    GrowColor(Xseed, Yseed);
    cvNamedWindow("wndname", 1);
    cvShowImage("original", Image1);

    cvShowImage("wndname", Image2);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;

}

void GrowColor(int x, int y) {
//Check to see if point already part of region

    s.val[0] = 0;
    s.val[1] = 0;
    s.val[2] = 0;
    s.val[3] = 0;
    if ((x < 1) && (y < 1))
        s = cvGet2D(Image2, x, y);

    if (s.val[0] == 0) {
        int k;
        if ((x == 1) && (y == 1))
            s11 = cvGet2D(Image1, x, y);
        mean[0] = total[0] / coont;
        mean[1] = total[1] / coont;
        mean[2] = total[2] / coont;

        temp[0] = abs(s11.val[0]) - mean[0];
        temp[1] = abs(s11.val[1]) - mean[1];
        temp[2] = abs(s11.val[2]) - mean[2];

        Diff =
                (int) (sqrt(
                        (temp[0] * temp[0] + temp[1] * temp[1]
                                + temp[2] * temp[2]) / 3));

        if (Diff < ThreshHold) {

            total[0] += abs(s11.val[0]);
            total[1] += abs(s11.val[1]);
            total[2] += abs(s11.val[2]);
            coont++;
            s.val[0] = 120;
            if ((x > 0) && (y > 0))
                cvSet2D(Image2, x, y, s);
            if (x > 2)
                GrowColor(x - 1, y);
            if (y > 2)
                GrowColor(x, y - 1);
            if (x < xDim - 2)
                GrowColor(x + 1, y);
            if (y < yDim - 2)
                GrowColor(x, y + 1);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making `GrowColor` a recursive function may result in an infinite loop. Check the code in that function once.

Comment: Good point. It might be worth inserting a few breakpoints to see how your code progresses.