# Ideas for cell segmentation - OpenCV

Tags: opencv, cells, image-segmentation, hsv, mser

I am trying to segment some cells from microscopic image. It looks like [this](http://img3.rajce.idnes.cz/d0303/11/11155/11155748_e10142a134e480b08b98a503f608ac0b/images/28.den40x2.jpg?ver=0) (sorry, can't post pictures yet).

I tried **Otsu thresholding**, for red channel (because cells are red), and it reduced most of the blue background, but some cells are joined into one object. Result can be found here in [this](http://xtmotoman.rajce.idnes.cz/Computer_vision) album (third picture).

So for this I tried **MSER**, but the results were not very good, it detected the small fat droplets, but not whole cells. If I use morphologic operations for joining these white segments, it joins some cells too. 
Result can be found in the same album, second image.

Because of different colors as next I tried **HSV thresholding** instead of MSER. I applied it on the Otsu threshed image. I found HSV values of the surrounding "blue" and segmented it away. It reduced most of the blue areas around the cells. For threshed image I used **findContours**, where I used only areas larger than 300px. Result looks like the last image in album above.

Does anybody have ideas about any more "robust" and useful method for this cell segmentation? Problem are various lighting conditions, where the HSV values are different.Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

You usually cannot expect robust and accurate results from simple thresholding approaches. You may want to give it a try with [watershed segmentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) or [region growing segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416511/seeded-region-growing-with-opencv) in OpenCV.

You will probably get some improvement but still you should not expect fabulous results. Robust approaches are usually the machine learning ones.

You need to manually segment some of your images, then train a classifier (SVM or random forest or neural network or ...) to classify each pixel (or patch) as being part of a cell or not. [cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) can be a good start since it is implemented in OpenCV.