# medical image segmentation with cv2

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using the MIAS data set of breast cancer mammography pictures. The data is available here:
http://peipa.essex.ac.uk/pix/mias/

for example, an image looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("mdb168.pgm",0)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

I want to remove all artifacts and unnecessary parts of the image.

To do this,I first binarize the image

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
plt.imshow(thresh1, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

use opening

```
kernel = np.ones((20,20),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
plt.imshow(opening, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

then erosion

```
kernel = np.ones((120,120),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(opening,kernel,iterations = 1)
plt.imshow(erosion, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

then merge this mask with the original image

```
merged = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img , mask=erosion)
plt.imshow(merged, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

I am now trying to remove the pectoral muscle in the upper left area.
In this publication: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26742491
they use the exact same data set and do this with `seeded region growing'.
However, there is no code provided and I could not find this in opencv.

I could achieve a similar result by doing dilate/erosion etc again, but I'm looking for a more generalizable solution.
Also, some of these images do not show a muscle and this should be detected as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no region growing algorithm in opencv but you can build one. Just initialize a seed point, upper and lower threshold and should work by iterating over the image. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416511/seeded-region-growing-with-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach:

1. (optional) I would replace the opening and the erosion with an opening by reconstruction <=> erosion followed by a geodesic dilation. It will preserve the original shape, and then you will keep a bigger ROI.
2. Convolution filter (gaussian or simple average) to smooth the image
3. Big white top-hat in order to detect the bright zone.
4. Then you subtract the top-hat result to the original image.

Comment: do you have an example for the top hat method? I read http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html but I do not understand how this works

Comment: Here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_transform In your example, it's simply Image-Opening(Image), and here is an illustration http://www.aishack.in/static/img/tut/morphology-tophat.jpg